# Vlookup unnested values using Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables where table 1 contains two columns: a column with a list of URLs embedded in string values (each cell contains more than one URL), and a date column. I managed to extract all unnested URLs to Table 2. I need to vlookup the two tables to get the date for each scraped URL (as in Tabel 3)

```
  Table 1    string | Date
              ______________
             STRING 1    Date 1     
             STRING 2    Date 2         
             STRING 3    Date 3  

  Table 2    Scraped URL |  string
             ______________________
             scraped URL 1  STRING 1
             scraped URL 2  STRING 2 
             scraped URL 3  STRING 3

  Table 3   scraped URL | Date
            _________________________
           scraped URL 1  Date 1
           scraped URL 2  Date 2
           scraped URL 3  Date 3
```

Comment: So what's the relation between `url` and `date`?

Comment: url are scraped from the string column in Table 1

Comment: Yes, but where does the date come from?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a `join`?

```
select t2.scraped_url, t1.date
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.scraped_url = t1.url
```

Comment: I've tried this query and for some reason it is giving me this error 'Cannot access field scraped_url on a value with type STRING at [1:13]'